# Correlation matrix and Wald Chi-square test in confirmatory factor analysis using lavaan package

Tags: r, correlation, matrix, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I saw a paper comparing correlations between the latent factors using Wald's chi-square test of parameter constrains. Anyone knows how to get the Wald's chi-square test result with correlation matrix, chi-square and p-values for the latent factors with 'lavaan' package? I was able to use inspect(fit,'cor.lv') to get the correlation matrix for the latent variables but now sure where to find the complete test results including chi-square and p-values. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: @JeremyMiles Test the correlations between the latent factors and report p-values, chi-square. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lavaan/versions/0.5-22/topics/lavTestWald

Comment: @JeremyMiles Thank you. That is testing the coefficients of the individual variables. How to test the correlations between the factors such as visual, textual and speed?

Comment: @JeremyMiles Thank you! I used the code to test the correlations between these three factors (visual ~~ r1 * speed+ r2*textual'). Does it look right? `' HS.model <- ' visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3 textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6 speed =~ x7 + x8 + x9 visual ~~ r1 * speed+ r2*textual' fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939) summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE) con = 'r1-r2==0' lavTestWald(fit, constraints = con) inspect(fit,'cor.lv') `

Comment: What was the result? The p-value should be very similar to the p-value for the parameter estimate (a likelihood based estimate), but a little lower.

Comment: I'm not sure. The p-value was `> lavTestWald(fit, constraints = con)
$stat
[1] 3.510788

$df
[1] 1

$p.value
[1] 0.06097045

$se
[1] "standard"
`

Comment: `> summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE)
lavaan (0.5-23.1097) converged normally after  35 iterations

  Number of observations                           301

  Estimator                                         ML
  Minimum Function Test Statistic               85.306
  Degrees of freedom                                24
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic              918.852
  Degrees of freedom                                36
  P-value                                        0.000
`

Comment: @JeremyMiles Sorry I don't know how to paste the results. I used the standard HolzingerSwineford1939 data and ran the CFA.

Comment: I will edit my answer. I missed part of your question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you have named a parameter in your model, you can use the lavTestWald function to test it.

In your model:

```
"visual ~~ r1 * speed"
```

Then to use the lavTestWald function:

```
lavTestWald(fit, constraints = "r1 == 0")
```